# How can I get the same behaviour navigating tabs if I use expandtab

Tags: vim, indentation

How can I get the same behaviour navigating tabs if I enable `expandtab`?

For example, assume 2 levels of indentation with a tabstop of 4 (█ represents the cursor), if my cursor is on the first `r` in this example:

```
        return 'world'
```

And I go left with <kbd>h</kbd> or <kbd>Left Arrow</kbd>, the cursor moves one space to the left:

```
       █return 'Hello, world'
```

But if I use tabs (0x09, `noexpandtab`), the cursor goes one *tab* to the left:

```
    █   return 'Hello, world'
```

I understand *why* this happens, but is there any way to get the tab behaviour when using `expandtab`? I work on some projects where `expandtab` is the norm, and some others where it isn't; I would like it to be consistent.

I already set `smarttab`, but this only affects the <kbd>Backspace</kbd> key. My `tabstop`, `softtabstop`, and `shiftwidth` settings are all set to 4. Using an empty `~/.vimrc` makes no difference.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Built-in motions like `h` and `<Left>` will always move by single characters. To get the behavior you want, I see two options:

- Override those motions with custom mappings that have that kind of "intelligence". Implementing this is certainly doable, but not trivial.
- With a set of `:autocmd`s, you can convert such buffers to use tab indent on read, and convert back to space indent on write. See `:help retab-example`. Then, the built-in motions will work (on those `<Tab>`s) as you'd like.

Alternatively, rethink your approach. If you're bothered by this, I think you're navigating too much in the indent. I personally mostly just skip it with `w` or `^`, and to reindent, I use `<<` / `>>`, which handle spaces just fine.

Comment: Thanks; using `:autocmd`/`:retab` is a good idea, but `retab` is flawed since it also changes **all** spaces to tabs, not just indentation; but with [your answer here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27548086/660921) I managed to use my own `Retab()` function with `autocmd`.

Answer (score 0):

The cursor is usually placed at the end of a tab character in normal mode, unless you have listmode (`:set list`) set. So the solution is easy, do not set listmode.

This is something, I just recently noticed myself. The documentation also states this (`:h 'list'`):

```
The cursor is displayed at the start of the space a Tab character
occupies, not at the end as usual in Normal mode.  To get this cursor
position while displaying Tabs with spaces, use: >
    :set list lcs=tab:\ \
```

Comment: While this is a useful hint, I don't really see how it relates to my question, as such? It doesn't seem to affect moving the cursor when `expandtab` is enabled (which is what the question is about).

Comment: The point was, depending on the 'list' setting the cursor either moves the the start of the Tab or the end. But well, I must have misunderstood your question, because for me the cursor moves as you wish.

Comment: Yes, but only when you're using tabs (0x09), I have a file with *space* indentation (`set expandtab`), which I would like to behave as if it's *tab indentation*.