# Replace all spaces at the start of the line with tabs

Tags: vim, indentation

I would like to replace all spaces at the start of the line with tabs. The below snippet works, but only for the first indentation level.

How do I make it work for *1 to ∞* indentation levels? So that it replaces 12 spaces with 3 tabs (assuming a `tabstop` of 4)?

```
fun! Retab()
    let l:spaces = repeat(' ', &tabstop)
    silent! execute '%s/^' . l:spaces . '/\t/g'
endfun
```

Note that using `:retab` doesn't seem to be an option here, since `:retab` doesn't just change indentation, but also changes all `repeat(' ', &tabstop)` occurrences *everywhere* in the file.

Re-indenting the file (with `=`) is also not an option, since Vim & I sometimes have different opinions on what should be indented at which level (ie. it has too many side-effects).

I also thought about using the `expand` & `unexpand` programs, but I would prefer not to rely on external utilities.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your attempt goes into the right direction, but you need `:help sub-replace-expr` to count the number of matched spaces and convert this into a corresponding number of tab characters:

```
silent! execute '%substitute#^\%(' . l:spaces . '\)\+#\=repeat("\t", len(submatch(0)) / &tabstop)#e'
```

To do the reverse (replaces tabs to spaces), you can do:

```
silent! execute '%substitute#^\%(\t\)\+#\=repeat("' . l:spaces . '", len(submatch(0)))#e'
```

Comment: Another way to convert tabs to spaces is `:set et` and then `>><<`.  Unfortunately that doesn't work to change a line to all tabs when it has spaces to the right of tabs.